# How do I delete the folders in a subfolder of a folder using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, document-library, subfolders

There is a document library folder named "Request Documents". There are folders in this folder Library. Again under each folder there is an other folder in it. I need to delete this folder. But I'm not able to delete it.
With the code below I'm able to delete the files inside the folder but not the folder. The message in the catch is being displayed. Can anyone help me with this?

```
   Function GetFiles($Folder)
  { 
   Write-Host "+"$Folder.Name
    #Loop through all subfolders and call the function recursively
    foreach ($SubFolder in $Folder.SubFolders)
    {
    if($SubFolder.Name -ne "Forms")
        {  
            Write-Host "`t" -NoNewline
            #Write-Host "+"$SubFolder.Name
            foreach($semisubfolders in $SubFolder.SubFolders)
            {
            if($semisubfolders.Name -eq 7754)
            {
                Write-Host "+"$semisubfolders.Name

                    try{
                         #$semisubfolders.Delete($semisubfolders)
                $SubFolder.SubFolders.DeleteItemById($semisubfolders.Item.ID)
                      write-host "Folder Deleted"
                       }
                    catch{
                            write-host "Not deleted or already deleted"
                       }


                       foreach($file in $semisubfolders.Files)
                       {    
                        Write-Host "Deleted File:" $file.Name
                        $Abcd.Items.DeleteItemById($file.Item.Id)
                        write-host "Deleted"
                       }

            }



        }



}



#Get the Site collection 
#$Site= Get-SPSite "http://idn-mapis2:1111/" 
    foreach($list in $web.Lists)
    {
        if($list.Title -eq "Request Documents")
        {
            GetFiles($List.RootFolder)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks to me as if your code blocks itself, either delete files first or force deletion of the folder.

Comment: Provided code is incomplete - there are two missing curly brackets (braces). Since the code is very poorly formatted, it is hard to understand where to place them. Please update code!

Answer (score 0):

What I am seeing you are deleting the files inside the folder, not folder itself. Please try below script and see if that resolve the issue.

```
$siteURL = "http://sharepoint.crescent.com/sites/sales"
$listName = "Documents"
$folderToDelete = "v2"

#Get the Web
$web = Get-SPWeb $siteURL 

#Get all Sub folders
$folders = $web.Folders[$listName].SubFolders

Foreach ($folder in $folders)
{
   if ($folder.Name -match $folderToDelete)
   {
        $web.Folders[$listName].SubFolders.Delete($folder);
        Write-Host "Folder has been deleted!"
   }
}
```

## Read more: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/05/delete-folders-sub-folders-from-sharepoint-library-programmatically.html#ixzz5ZHuTKwER